# Groups with all normal subgroups characteristic

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Today in my research, I had to use fairly explicitly the rather tautological property of finite cyclic groups that every normal subgroup is characteristic, i.e. fixed by all automorphisms. This got me wondering:

> do (finite) groups with the property that every normal subgroup is characteristic
> have a name and/or can they be completely
> classified? Generally, has this
> property been investigated at all?

Apart from cyclic groups, some groups possessing the above property that immediately come to mind are simple groups, symmetric groups, [semi-dihedral groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasidihedral_group), and dihedral groups of twice odd order (however not of twice even order).

This is as far as I got on my short walk home (apart from some false claims, see comments). I suspect that this property might be well studied.

**Edit**:
The reference that Beren Sanders provided in his answer and the references to and from it all deal with $p$-groups. I still haven't been able to find anything about arbitrary finite groups. Some of the questions that $p$-group theorists ask are just not terribly interesting in the case of arbitrary groups. E.g. the paper that Beren Sanders mentioned proves that every finite $p$-group is contained in another finite $p$-group in which every normal subgroup is characteristic. The same statement for arbitrary finite groups is trivial: just embed your group into a symmetric group. I would still be surprised if nobody had tried to say something reasonably general about finite groups with this property.

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but, if it's not too much trouble, can someone give an example of a normal subgroup that isn't characteristic? 

Comment: Any subgroup of index 2 in the quaternion group of order 8.

Comment: Could you explain why the property is inherited by normal subgroups ?

Comment: @BS I am sorry, that was a mistake. I meant quotient groups and not normal subgroups. I can't think of any counter examples to the latter, but nor can I see why it should be true.

Comment: @Alex: are you sure that quotient groups inherit the property? It seems that the group $G:=S_5 \times S_7$ has abelianization that is a product of two cyclic groups of order 2. In particular, every non-trivial subgroup of the abelianization is normal, but not characteristic. On the other hand, if I am not mistaken, the only normal subgroups of $G$ are also characteristic.

Comment: Actually, here is a counterexample to the original claim that the property is inherited by normal subgroups: $V_4$ in $S_4$. One can probably obtain many more by taking semi-direct products of groups that don't have the property by their outer automorphism groups.

Comment: @damiano Thanks, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Normal subgroups of [complete groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_group) are characteristic.

Comment: Of course it won't help in describing these groups, but the condition means that the $\mathrm{Out}(G)$-action on the lattice $\mathcal{N}(G)$ of normal subgroups of $G$ is trivial. Trivial (already mentioned) instances are when one of the two is "trivial": when $\mathrm{Out}(G)=\{1\}$ or when $G$ is simple.

Answer (score 15):

> The question in which $p$-groups all normal subgroups are characteristic is a fairly old problem in the theory of finite $p$-groups. It seems difficult to assess because of the fact that neither subgroups nor factors of a group which has none but characteristic normal subgroups need retain this property.

These are the first two sentences of the following 2009 paper published in the Israel Journal of Mathematics:

B. Wilkens. [$p$-groups without noncharacteristic normal subgroups.](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11856-009-0078-x) Isr. J. Math. 172, 357–369 (2009). [Zbl 1188.20014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1188.20014)

As a non-expert I have nothing more to add.

Comment: That's an interesting pointer, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Here is a small contribution. If no two factors in a composition series for $G$ are isomorphic, then every normal subgroup of $G$ is characteristic. In fact, in groups of this type, no two distinct normal subgroups can be isomorphic. To see this, suppose $M$ and $N$ are distinct and isomorphic. Look at a composition series obtained by refining the series $1 \subseteq M \cap N < M <MN \subseteq G$. Let $S$ be a simple group occurring as a composition factor between $M \cap N$ and $M$. Then $S$ is not isomorphic to a composition factor of $M \cap N$, but it is a composition factor of $M$ and hence also of the isomorphic group $N$. Since $S$ is a composition factor of $N$ but not of $M \cap N$, it is a composition factor of $N/(N \cap M)$. Since this group is isomorphic to $MN/M$, we see that $MN/M$ has $S$ as a composition factor. This is a contradiction because then $G$ has two composition factors isomorphic to $S$: one between $M \cap N$ and $M$ and another between $M$ and $MN$.

Comment: (1) I'd like to recall the old problem of study of the $p$-groups all of whose maximal subgroups are characteristic. (2) Does there exist a noncyclic group of exponent $p$, all of whose maximal subgroups are characteristic? (3) Is it true that if all subgroups of order $p$ from $\text{Z}(G)$ are characteristic in the $p$-group $G$, then $|\Omega_1(\text{Z}(G))|$ is bounded?